# evaluate json object in java

Tags: java, json

i wan to get values from a json string that looks like that in my java programm:  `{"2":["1.1.9.1","abc","1398422038"],"1":["75.224.11.33","test","1398384362"],"0":["125.234.22.33","test","1398382882"],"_size":3}`

I tried it like that:

```
int length = result.optInt("_size");

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    JSONArray result2 = result.getJSONArray(String.valueOf(i));
    IPBans.addBan(result2.getString(0), 
            result2.getString(1), 
            result2.getString(3));
}
```

But it does not work. result is the JSONObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only 3 sub items for each array, so you need to index 0,1,2. Searching fo element in 3° position will always fail.

Try to change

```
result2.getString(3)
```

to

```
result2.getString(2)
```

Comment: Super, it works. Thank you so mouch! I am too bad :/